# finding exact matches for your name when name is around 100 characters long?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
text="Sfs gsk fsd exc gsk gks";
var myName="gsk";
var hits=[];
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
{
  if(text[i]=="g"&&text[i+1]=="s"&&text[i+2]=="k")
  {
    for(var j=i;j<(i+myName.length);j++)
    {
      hits.push(text[j]);
    }
  }
}
if(hits===0)
  console.log("your name is not in array");
else
  console.log(hits);
```

Here o/p is like :: `[ 'g', 's', 'k', 'g', 's', 'k' ]`

Now, what if the var `myName` is 100 characters long?

Comment: You really need to have a proper indenting. Also your code is hard to read because of your (lack) of formatting e.g. you should leave spaces around operators. Propper code formatting is very important, please don't overlook it.

Comment: @bolov : Thanx for your suggestion...i'll follow in future surely..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find `myName` in `text`, this would be a better approach ihmo:

```
var text = 'sfs,gsk,fsd,exc,gsk,gks'.split(',')
//          ^ create an Array by splitting a string (on the comma)
   ,myName = 'gsk'
   ,otherName = 'aVeryLongAndStrangeNameWellItsNotHundredCharsButItsLongStill'
   ,myNameExists = text.indexOf(myName.toLowerCase()) > -1 // => true
//                                     ^check case insensitive   
   ,otherNameExists = text.indexOf(otherName.toLowerCase()) > -1// => false

// display:
console.log(myNameExists ? myName : 'myName not in text');
console.log(otherNameExists ? otherName : 'otherName not in text');
```

The `indexOf` method checks for the existence of the parameter (e.g. `myName`) in the Array, and it there is a match, it returns the index of the Array element. The index is > -1 in case of a match.

If by 'exact' you mean case sensitive, remove `.toLowerCase()`

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on `indexOf` for Arrays

Comment: im quite new to JS can u please elaborate what u said?Thanx for replying

Comment: I've added some explanation. But maybe you should first follow a tutorial (check http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript)

Comment: If string 'otherName' is present in an array 'text'...how do i display    otherName alone as output like [ 'a', 'V', 'e', 'r', 'y', 'L','o'....so on up to....'t','i','l','l'].And what is the if condition we have to use.

Comment: i want to display whole name as output like i have shown above and not whether it is present or not?I hope u understand my question..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try jQuery's .inArray()

Something like this

```
var text=["Sfs", "gsk", "fsd", "exc", "gsk", "gks"];
var myName = "gsk";
var hits = jQuery.inArray( myName, text ); // returns 1

if(hits >= 0){ // name found }
else {// name not found }
```